# Which one are the supported iOS versions for development

Tags: ios, xcode

I was googling a lot and I can't find anywhere if there is support to iOS 4.xxx

I have XCode 4.3.1 and in the Schemes I just have iOS device / iPhone 5.1 Simulator / iPad 5.1 Simulator.

Is still supported iOS 4.xxx for development? Or is just supported iOS 5.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is, in the Xcode preferences go to the downloads tab, here you can download the iOS 4 simulator as well as 4.0 debugging support.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Irene has mentioned, you can check under Preferences->Downloads to ensure that you have the simulators and libraries installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported, but you need to be careful with which APIs are you using. This article called "[SDKs and Deployment Targets](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/)" has helped me a lot, so read it and let us know if you need more information.